# Logs showing WARNING when trying to credit bank accounts with Balanced Payments

Tags: balanced-payments

Been seeing this in my logs today.

```
  #############################################################
  #   WARNING! WARNING! WARNING! WARNING! WARNING! WARNING!   #
  #############################################################

  Using positional arguments is **DEPRECATED**. Please use the
  keyword options pattern instead. Version __0.7.0__ of the
  Ruby client will not support positional arguments.
```

The code that is responsible for that is:

```
bank_account.credit((amount*100).to_i)
```

What do I change? Couldn't find anything in the docs either.
https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/api?language=ruby#credit-an-existing-bank-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bank_account.credit(:amount => (amount*100).to_i)` should do the trick. The error you are getting is warning you from using positional arguments e.g.
`def example(positional_arg1, positional_arg2);end`

A good example of how to properly use the ruby client can be found [here](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/blob/master/examples/customers.rb).

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line to:

```
bank_account.credit(:amount => (amount*100).to_i)
```